# How to show form elements from one form to another form in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two HTML pages and both of them contain a form. For example, I call **Register.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <form name="fform" action="confirmation.html">
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="Register()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to show what I entered on that form on this HTML page. For example I call **confirmation.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <p> Congratulations, User with data below: </p>
    <form name="fform">
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="zname">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="zemail">
    </form>
    <p> Has been Successfully Registered! </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JS that I call with **menu.js**:

```
var namestr = (document.fform.name.value);
(document.fform.zname.value) = namestr;

var emailstr = (document.fform.email.value);
(document.fform.zemail.value) = emailstr;

document.fform.submit();
```

What is the right JS code for the `Register()` function so the all of form elements value from **Register.html** are displayed in **confirmation.html**, since my JS is not working, the elements value is not shown in **confirmation.html**.

(I prefer that you use HTML and JS only, because I only understand those languages).

Comment: so many questions. hmm what are you using? are you building a SPA or is a page to page app? is the server in your control? is it server side rendered or ajax based?

Comment: No, it just a simple page with javascript. It's pure js and html

Answer (score 0):

For this simple task you can use [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

To save data on `Register.html`:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", document.fform.name.value);
```

To get data on `confirmation.html`:

```
document.fform.zname.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
```